# $and operator on multiple $text search in mongo

Tags: mongodb, full-text-indexing

Is it possible to have $and operator on multiple $text index search in mongo?

I have documents in tp collection of my db

```
> db.tp.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("...."), "name" : "tp", "dict" : { "item1" : "random", "item2" : "some" } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("...."), "name" : "tp", "dict" : { "item3" : "rom", "item4" : "tttt" } }
```

Then I do

```
> db.tp.createIndex({ "$**": "text" })
> db.tp.find({ $and: [{$text : { $search: "random" } }, {$text : { $search: "redruth" } }]})
```

And it fails with

```
Error: error: {
"waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Too many text expressions",
"code" : 2
}
```

but text index search works for single search so is it not possible to bind multiple text searches with $and operator? By the way I am using wildcard character `$**` for indexing because I want to search over entire document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query can specify at most one `$text` expression. See:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Comment: so is there any way to have two strings match on a $text field? I cannot find a way.

Answer (score 7):

Base on [mongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) docs, AND operator can use directly in search term by combining quote and space. For example, we search for "ssl certificate" AND "authority key", so the query should like:

```
> db.tp.find({'$text': {'$search': '"ssl certificate" "authority key"'}})
```